# How to integrate outlook with an application running on IIS?

Tags: email, iis, outlook, integration

I have an application running on IIS. I have a webpage that contains normal EmailTo, cc, Body etc. fields. I want to integrate client outlook to this page. Please guide me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Use mailto url on the web page.
2. in case of IE, you can use the Outlook Object Model in you client side script, but your site must be trusted to be able to do that.
3. On the server side, you can use EWS to connect to Exchange Server if that is what the user uses. But you will need to know the user name and password.